# Laravel OCI8 : Getting syntax error, unexpected '|', expecting ';' or '{' on OCI8.php

Tags: php, docker

I'm setting up my a docker container with PHP 7.4 and OCI8

Im installing instantclient via zip file and unzipping it using the dockerfile.
it was successful in building and mounting but when i try to send a request to the controller it returns syntax error, unexpected '|', expecting ';' or '{' in /var/www/html/vendor/yajra/laravel-pdo-via-oci8/src/Pdo/Oci8.php (line 353).

does this mean oci8 was not install successfully or i'm my zip file for the instantclient is outdate? does anyone have an idea of this issue

[image]

Dockerfile for reference

```
    FROM composer:2.0 as vendor

COPY composer.json/ /app/composer.json
COPY docker/config/nginx.conf /app/nginx.conf

RUN composer install \
    --ignore-platform-reqs \
    --no-interaction \
    --no-plugins \
    --no-scripts \
    --no-ansi \
    --prefer-dist


FROM alpine:3.14
LABEL Maintainer="Christian Jay Bayno"

# Install packages
RUN apk --no-cache add php7 \
php7-fpm \
php7-phalcon \
php7-pdo_mysql \
php7-json \
php7-openssl \
php7-curl \
php7-tokenizer \
php7-dom \
php7-dev \
php7-opcache \
nginx \
supervisor \
curl \
git \
tzdata \
g++ \
gcc \
make \
libaio-dev \
libnsl \
gcompat

RUN ln -s /usr/lib/libnsl.so.2 /usr/lib/libnsl.so.1

# Install Instaclient and PDO OCI
RUN mkdir -p /opt/oci

COPY ./docker/oracle/instantclient-basic-19.17.0.0.0.zip /opt/oci
COPY ./docker/oracle/instantclient-sdk-19.17.0.0.0.zip /opt/oci
COPY ./docker/oracle/pdo_oci.zip /opt/oci
RUN cd /opt/oci \
    && unzip instantclient-basic-19.17.0.0.0.zip \
    && unzip instantclient-sdk-19.17.0.0.0.zip \
    && cd instantclient_19_17/ \
    && ln -s /opt/oci/instantclient_19_17/libclntsh.so.12.1 libclntsh.so \
    && ln -s /opt/oci/instantclient_19_17/libocci.so.12.1 libocci.so \
    && ls \ 
    && cd ../ \
    && unzip pdo_oci.zip \
    && cd pdo_oci \
    && phpize \
    && ./configure --with-pdo-oci=shared,instantclient,/opt/oci/instantclient_19_17 \
    && make \
    && make install \
    && echo "extension=oci8.so" >> /etc/php7/conf.d/pdo_oci.ini \
    && echo "extension=pdo_oci.so" >> /etc/php7/conf.d/pdo_oci.ini \
    && cd /opt/oci \
    && rm *.zip

# Configure Timezone
ENV TZ Asia/Manila

# Configure nginx
COPY docker/config/nginx.conf /etc/nginx/nginx.conf

# Configure PHP-FPM
COPY docker/config/fpm-pool.conf /etc/php7/php-fpm.d/www.conf
COPY docker/config/php.ini /etc/php7/conf.d/app.ini

# Configure supervisord
COPY docker/config/supervisord.conf /etc/supervisor/conf.d/supervisord.conf

# Make sure files/folders needed by the processes are accessable when they run under the nobody user
RUN chown -R nobody.nobody /run && \
  chown -R nobody.nobody /var/lib/nginx && \
  chown -R nobody.nobody /var/log/nginx

# Set up document root
RUN mkdir -p /var/www/html

# Switch to use a non-root user from here on
USER nobody

# Add application
WORKDIR /var/www/html
COPY --chown=nobody . /var/www/html/
COPY --chown=nobody --from=vendor /app/vendor/ /var/www/html/vendor/

# Expose the port nginx is reachable on
EXPOSE 8085

# Let supervisord start nginx & php-fpm
CMD ["/usr/bin/supervisord", "-c", "/etc/supervisor/conf.d/supervisord.conf"]

# Configure a healthcheck to validate that everything is up&running
HEALTHCHECK --timeout=10s CMD curl --silent --fail http://127.0.0.1:8085/fpm-ping
```

Comment: return types `false|string` are not supported in php7.4. PHP 8 supports that.

Comment: oh, i see. so this means my yajra/laravel-oci8 in the composer.json  is incompatible right?

Comment: Seems so https://github.com/yajra/laravel-oci8/blob/9.x/composer.json but why not switch to php8 in your dockerfile?

Comment: ill try to update it too to php8 tho still figuring out how this works. thank you :)

Comment: tried changing all the php7 to php8  but still and error

Comment: What kind of error?

Comment: got some connection refused upon checking docker logs